# Submiting Ajax form in Net .Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created wizard with the `jQuery-Steps` lib with simple form for now. There is no **Submit** button. I submit form on finish step via jQuery.

I am already using jQuery calls all over the place, and I have included all scripts, and I needed form for uploading images and other stuff, it's easier with it.

Nothing happens, the controller action is not called.

I just getting redirected on start page with all this parameters in query string.

Like this:

```
https://localhost:44380/Dashboard?Name=Aaaa&Surename=Bbbb&City=Cccc
```

Dashboard is all made with Ajax and partial views. And from person option in menu I'm getting redirected on home view in Dashboard with all this parameters.

This is the form:

```
<form asp-controller="PersonSettings" asp-action="SaveForm" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" id="personForm" class="steps-validation wizard-notification">
    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <h6>Person</h6>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">
                        Person Name :
                        <span class="danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control required" id="Name" name="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Surname">
                        Person Surname:
                        <span class="danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="url" class="form-control required" id="Surname" name="Surname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="City">
                        Person City:
                        <span class="danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="url" class="form-control required" id="City" name="City">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the Model:

```
public class PersonDto {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Action in PersonSettings controller:

```
[Route("SaveForm")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveForm(PersonDto Person) {
   //Do something with person model
   return Ok();
}
```

And on finish button I have jQuery submit called on this form:

```
 $('#personForm').submit();
```

EDIT:

I tried with this parameters:

```
<form action="PersonSettings/SaveForm" method="post" id="personFrom" class="steps-validation wizard-notification">
```

And this works.. it's good, but why does the first method not work? Because I need this in Ajax and finish method.

I didn't find any way to post image with form with classic Ajax call. Because I can't read image path (it's not exposed to the browsers).

Comment: `Nothing happens, Controller Action is not called` : is the call being made, and if so; what is the server's response? (can be 400, 404, 500 etc.)

Comment: Check my edited answer. I don't see that Action is called. I checked in network tab, only activity (beside loading page etc) is one with /Dashboard with parameters. My Dashboard controller is different from one that I calling with form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't installed Tag Helpers. If it works with action attribute, it should work with Tag Helpers attribute. Because you're using Asp-Net-Controller attribute.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Please let me know.

Comment: Now it works, thank you. Problem is it's is redirecting me to another page. I tried with replace parameter and onComplete function but it's not working. But you answered on question, this is another problem now.